# Where did my answer go?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I believe I had an answer to [Protestant arguments for perpetual virginity of Mary](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/320/protestant-arguments-for-perpetual-virginity-of-mary). Where did it go?

Mods?

If I recall correctly, my answer was based on this article:

[Mary: Perpetual Virgin? 6 Biblical Arguments](http://www.setonmagazine.com/latest-articles/mary-perpetual-virgin)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no deleted answers on this question right now, so unless one was completely wiped from the database ([which is done only in exceptional cases](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107986/300411)), you have not answered this question.

You did, however, answer the following related question:

- [Did Mary have other children?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/31359/21576)

This answer cites the article you mention. Is that the one you are thinking of?

FYI, I found this by putting the following in the search box:

```
user:13992 mary virgin is:answer
```